# Voltage Issue on ground

Tags: electrical

On several outlets feeding from a sub panel (ground & neutral not tied together in panel) I am getting 121v from hot leg to neutral. But when I go from hot leg to ground I am getting 85v on one leg of the 240v side and 155v when I go to the other leg of the 240v side. Under load the voltage from hot leg to either side stays a steady 121v (Not suspecting an open neutral) In sub panel being fed with #10 thhn, there is no ground bar, all the grounds are tied together going back to main panel with a ground wire tied in to the sub panel thru a bonding screw in back of panel. What could be causing this?

Comment: Was the neutral bar/bus in the panel isolated from ground?  Quite often a screw or strap needs to be removed to isolate it.

Comment: What is the voltage reading between ground and neutral?  It should be ~0v.

Comment: Symptoms seem like your ground in the sub-panel is not tied back to the main panel and is floating.